# Regex - how to test characters before the last last character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to determine the pattern for comparing the last character of a string is "y" (y$).

My problem is how to also test if "y" is precedeed by a vowel [aeiou].

Comment: I really don't see what is the problem.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: are you sure???

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte For a pattern matching a string where the last character is `y` and the preceding character is a vowel? Yes

Comment: wah? that's it? after all the combo i tried, don't know why i didn't even try that. thank you!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: You are right obviously, but it wasn't really a question.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about capturing and just need a matching pattern, simply combine the two:

```
[aeiou]y$
```

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to post here another useful approach - at least it is always good to know: The Positive Lookbehind:

`~(?<=[aeiou])y$~`

It will match strings ending with vowel + y like 'yay' but not 'chubby' haha.

Explanations:

- `~`: delimiter
- `(?<=)`: look behind block
- `[aeiou]`: match character among those vowels
- `y`: match char literally
- `$`: match end of string

You can play with it here on perfect online editor: https://regex101.com/r/uJ3eA8/1
:)

Answer (score 0):

thank you. how about if doing the inverse? want to match text that ends in y, but y is NOT preceeded by a vowel?

this appears to work, i am hoping for just one test to do the job.

```
Regex:Match(myText, "y$", RegexOptions:IgnoreCase):Success and 
  not Regex:Match(myText, "[aeiou]+.$", RegexOptions:IgnoreCase):Success
```

Comment: Then you can do `~(?<![aeiou])y$~`!  And it will be the negative lookbehind! ;)